# R: Using the "names" function on a dataset created within a loop

Tags: r, paste, assign, names

I am using a for loop to read in multiple csv files and naming the datasets import1, import2, etc. For example:

```
assign(paste("import",i,sep=""), read.csv(files[i], header=FALSE))
```

However, I now want to rename the variables in each dataset. I have tried the following:

```
names(as.name(paste("import",i,sep=""))) <- c("xxxx", "yyyy")
```

But get the error "target of assignment expands to non-language object". (I need to change the name of variables in each dataset **within** the loop as the variable names need to be different in each dataset).

Any suggestions on how to do this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to read the files into a list of data.frames, instead of one data.frame object per file. Assuming `files` is the vector of file names (as you imply above):

```
import <- lapply(files, read.csv, header=FALSE)
```

Then if you want to operate on each data.frame in the list using a loop, you easily can:

```
for (i in seq_along(import)) names(import[[i]]) <- c('xxx', 'yyy')
```

Comment: You're looping through this twice, when you only need to do it once if you use `setNames`: `import <- lapply(files, function(x) setNames(read.csv(x, header=FALSE), c('xxx','yyy')))`

Comment: Yes, but I constructed the answer like that intentionally to illustrate two different concepts: 1) using a list to store related objects 2) operating on a list of objects. I thought that would be most helpful to OP. If we're aiming for maximally compact solutions, though, there's also `import <- lapply(files, read.csv, header=FALSE, col.names = c('xxx', 'yyy'))`  which avoids the need for the anon function

Answer (score 1):

While I do agree it would be much better to keep your data.frames in a list rather than creating a bunch of variables in your global environment, you can also set names when you read the files in

```
assign(paste("import",i,sep=""), 
    read.csv(files[i], header=FALSE, col.names=c("xxxx", "yyyy")))
```

Using `assign()` isn't very "R-like".